# what is __open() and why is fopen() calling it instead of open?

Tags: c, linux, fopen, glibc

Looking at the source for Linux C standard library, I see that the source for the function `fopen` uses `open` which one might think is *the* `open` system call, but it is not, instead in the standard library source it is defined as

```
# define open(Name, Flags, Prot) __open (Name, Flags, Prot)
```

Indeed I checked that if I comment out the above line and recompile the standard library, then the resulting `fopen` works just fine and does call the system call `open`.

I can find a lot of documentation for `open` but none for `__open`.

Then I am confused...  What is `__open`, where is it documented and why is `fopen` calling it instead of `open`?

Comment: `open()` is syscall. `fopen()` is more high-level routine from C Standard Library. See `man 2 open` and `man 3 fopen` for details.

Comment: I just checked it with `strace` tool: `fopen()` calls `open()` for me. So `__open()` must be calling `open()` in the end. Must be some sort of wrapper.

Comment: @SamProtsenko why are you telling me what `open` and `fopen` are - I know that very well and it does not have anything to do with my question.  I also checked `strace` and it also prints `open` when calling `fopen`, yet, this is just a printout and does not necessarily mean the `open` syscall is called.

Comment: Misunderstood your question. But you are wrong about `strace`. It's not just some printout, it's reliable thing. And I'm pretty sure that `fopen()` called `open()` (at least on my Debian testing amd64 system), because it showed exactly the same file that I provided to `fopen()`, but only in `open()` syscall.

Comment: _open is probably lower level function called by open(). In my research {_isalpha()} does the same as {isalpha()} , but without safety checks.  I have a feeling {open()} and {_open()} have the same relationship.

Comment: @SamProtsenko I checked with `LD_PRELOAD`:  when I comment out the line, `open` is called, which means, it is loaded dynamically so that `LD_PRELOAD` is valid, however, if I do not comment, it is not called.  It is a sure thing.

Comment: @MarkGaleck I didn't quite catch that thing about `LD_PRELOAD`. Can you elaborate? I mean, I know what it is, I just can't understand what you did.

Comment: @MarkGaleck Ah, you mean you are substituting custom built glibc using `LD_PRELOAD`? If so, can you confirm that `__libc_open()` is being called on `fopen()` (`sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/generic/open.c` file)? I mean, try to add some stuff there (like some distinctive syscall that you can catch with `strace`) to be sure that function is what **really** being called on `fopen()`.

Comment: @SamProtsenko thank you for helping me!  Not exactly, that is not what I am doing.  I take the source of `glibc` and change it to experiment and understand how it works.  I recompile that and substitute for the system installation of `glibc`.  Additionally, I use the `LD_PRELOAD` trick to intercept various calls, some of them are in my changed library.

Answer (score 0):

This is an internal compile-time redirection. The standard interface of POSIX `fcntl.h` is `open`. This is what you are supposed to call from your code. The leading underscores are a clear hint, that this is an internal implementation-defined thing. It should be transparent to you when using `open`.

It is not really apparent to me why exactly this is done on your system. With such macro redirects one can for instance chose between different internal functions based on compile-time-flags. So usually there is a set of `#if` around those `#define`s. In the case of the file functions, this is for example used to redirect the default versions to the 64-bit versions when `__USE_FILE_OFFSET64` is set. You have to do it that way, because you cannot simply change the interface of the existing functions.

Another reason to do that can be to can be to redirect a function, e.g. `sprintf` to a safer version, again depending on compiler flags. Or to have C code actually call Fortran-compatible symbols.

This can also cause issues, e.g. when trying to execute functions via `dlsym`.

Comment: @MarkGaleck What "standard library"? Please provide a link. The "C standard library" is only a document specifying an interface. It does not have a source code. There are implementations of it...

Comment: C standard library implementation by GNU https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/  I got the source, made changes, recompiled and used the new library to experiment

Comment: it is not "on my system" - the above line is in the source of the current version of the standard library, taken from the web, nothing to do with specifics on my system.